# In/with a capital letter

Tags: prepositions

With preposition is correct? I think both, but there's got to be a difference.
; This word is to be written in/with a capital letter.

Comment: Nitpicking, but: You can write a word "in **a** capital letter" only if said word has exactly **one** letter, otherwise it would be letter**s**.

Comment: @Stephie: My thoughts exactly! But idiomatically I think I'd prefer *In English we always write the first person singular **with / using** a capital letter*, even though syntactically *and* semantically, ***in*** works fine for single-letter words.

Comment: Note that in contexts like *You should always capitalise this word*, it's potentially ambiguous as to whether that means capitalise *all* letters, or just the *first.*

Answer (score 2):

"With a capital letter" (giving the meaning of using)

But one would say "write the word in capitals". That means using uppercase letters throughout.

> Write "dandelion" with a capital letter - > "Dandelion"

> Write "dandelion" in capitals -> "DANDELION"

Comment: You can also say **Capitalise** "dandelion" > Dandelion

Comment: But if I say, "Write the following words in capital letters," does it mean that all the letters of the words?

Comment: Yes, this is a technical distinction that most native speakers don't care about.

Comment: @MrDandelion Official forms frequently instruct those filling them in to write names and addresses in capital letters (for the sake of clarity) meaning that you use capitals throughout.

Comment: I've deleted the part about uppercase letters. It wasn't wrong but it was unnecessary and may have been confusing